# How do you keep the previous Android activity data visible upon returning from the Back Button (<-) on the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-activity

**Scenario setup**: The Main Activity has a Recycler view list that populates a list of items when selecting a topic. When an Item in the list is clicked, it will take the user to the Details Activity which provides specific details on that topic (similar to a notes app I guess).

**My Problem**: When I click the back arrow (<-) on the left of the toolbar on the Details Activity to return to the list of items on the Main Activity, all the fields and list of items are empty on the Main Activity.

However, if I use the device back Button and not the toolbar back arrow, when I return to the Main Activity, all the details are still there for the topic I selected. This is also true if I run in debug mode and step through the code **onOptionsItemSelected** with the **finish()**, the Main Activity fields and list are still populated.  However, when simply running the app (not debugging or using the device back button), the Main Activity fields and list are empty when I return.

**What I have tried**: When I debug the following code works but I'm not sure if it is the correct way correct. I have tried including the onBackPressed method. I'm also not sure how you identify this Back Arrow on the toolbar to call it properly.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have tried this as well:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you return with up button (the back arrow on the toolbar), framework sends an intent to MainActivity in the background. And by default, this creates a new instance of your MainActivity. Returning with the back button at the bottom on the other hand, pops your DetailsActivity off the backstack and show the existing instance of MainActivity, doesn't create a new instance. This is the reason of the different behaviour.

For solution, you can add:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to your manifest, within the tags of your MainActivity. With singleTop launch mode it will not create a new instance each time, it will bring the existing instance to front.

Another possible solution is to force your up button to work like back button in your DetailsActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getId() == android.R.id.home){
       onBackPressed()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! I used the first option, and thanks for explaining.